# How to select/ask more breeds at once?

Tags: netlogo, agent, agent-based-modeling

I have 8 different breeds in my model. Some of them share similar traits. 
Anyway, lets suppose that my breeds are

```
breed [ humans human ]
breed [ dogs dog ]
breed [ cats cat ]
breed [ horses horse ]
breed [ elephants elephant ]
breed [ mouses mouse ]
breed [ monkeys monkey ]
breed [ birds bird ]
```

My question is how to ask for example everyone except birds. I don't want to ask each breed individually. I know that when you want to ask every breed than you go with `ask turtles`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will want some combination of `turtle-set` and `member?` primitives. For example, `let wanted (turtle-set humans horses mouses)` will get an agentset named 'wanted' with all the humans, horses and mouses. For your specific example, `let wanted turtles with [not member? self birds]` will get all the turtles except birds.

Comment: I'd suggest preferring `breed != birds` to `not member? self birds`

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget that turtles have a built-in variable `breed` (look it up). All you need is ask `turtles with [breed != birds]`